# Can I spread the invocations of AWS Lambda out over a 5-minute interval?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a Lambda that runs **every** 5 minutes repeatedly. It performs a data processing task (query a third party API and process the response) once per user. This produces a spike of data every 5 minutes.

I want to convert that spike of data into an even spread of data every second. Is there any way I can spread that repeated task out over multiple Lambda invocations across the 5 minutes, for a more even spread of data?

My goal is to get evenly spread data output over time, so that I can pipe it into AWS Kinesis as if it were real-time streaming data.

edit:

Right now, my Lambda runs every 5 minutes via Cloudwatch event. It queries my server for user API keys and then queries a third party API, processes the result and stores it in DynamoDB.

I want to spread the load evenly over 5 minutes, so that users will be processed in one batch per second, producing an even output.

I am thinking that I could split my userbase into 300 buckets (one per second of 5 mins) in Memcached, and then run a tiny EC2 instance which will get the buckets from Memcached and trigger a Lambda for each bucket every second. Is there any better way of achieving this?

Comment: Can you elaborate further on your stack? How is your lambda get triggered(cloudwatch event rule or other ways)? What source does your lambda process data from?

Comment: @congbaoguier I updated the question

Comment: What does this proposed architecture give you above having your current Lambda posting to Dynamo more often, I.e. looping through your users and posting results after every x number of calls to the 3rd party api?

Comment: Maybe AWS Step Functions with iterator pattern (see https://read.acloud.guru/processing-an-arbitrary-number-of-jobs-with-aws-step-functions-c185c2d2608)

Comment: if you ec2 is going basically non-idle, it's actually a good idea. Still, you might want to calculate out how much exact odle time you going to have and do the math on cost against per second Lambda approach. Serverless is not the optimal solution to everything. It's just an option. Only use it when it does save money vs. using a mostly idle ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

[image: another aws diagram]

I am currently assuming you need to throttle your API calls due to the 3rd API rate limiting the service.

There are a few ways to solve this problem, so pick the one that suits you best. My take is keeping it simple/serverless and just invoking a second lambda every second to process a batch of users.

Events:

1. Cloudwatch event invokes Lambda A every 5 mins
2. Lambda A gets API key and list of users to query from "private server"
3. Lambda A splits list of users into <300 chunks. (I say less than 300 because we dont want to run up to the 5 min mark and have a possible overlap with next Lambda A invocation. Or you can change the Cloudwatch trigger frequency to >5 mins)
4. Lambda A process each of the <300 chunks in synchronously in order and invoke Lambda B asynchronously every second.

The outgoing GET requests from Lambda B to the 3rd party server should then be rather even at ~1 request per second. The response time and writing to dynamoDb on the other hand may vary.

Comment: If we're splitting the users into ~300 chunks and running one chunk per second, that means that I have a Lambda that is constantly running, mostly idle, costing a lot of $$$. Hence why I thought that Lambda A would be better off as a cheap EC2 instance. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, Lambda costs will be more expensive than EC2, but a big chunk will be coming from Lambda B. Assuming we are completely outside the free tier and running the 128MB lambda.
    
**Lambda Request Costs ~ $0.6 per month**
- LambdaA called 8750 times per month. (5 min interval)
- LambdaB called 2,625,000 times per month (300 chunk)
    
**Lambda Duration Costs ~ $33 per month**
- LambdaA runs 2,625,000 seconds per month ($5)
- LambdaB runs 13,125,000 seconds per month ($28) (5sec invocation)
 
T2.nano EC2 instance costs ~ $4-5 a month. (will also need to consider data transfer costs)

Comment: So if cost is the main driver, then perhaps moving to a tiny ec2 instance to encompass LambdaA and LambdaB logic might be the way forward.

Comment: My thinking is that Lambda A must be running for 5 minutes continuously in order to process 300 chunks at 1 chunk per second. It will process a chunk and call Lambda B, then wait, then process another and call Lambda B, then wait, etc.. That means that Lambda A runs constantly. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it will run continuously for 5 mins but not 24/7. Each cloudwatch trigger will invoke a separate Lambda. It will not cause the same lambda to continue running. So if you have >300 chunks with a 5 min interval you can have an overlap and have 2 Lamdba A's running concurrently for a short period of time. FYI the maximum running time of a lambda invocation is 15 mins

Comment: Right, so I forgot to mention that Lambda A runs EVERY 5 minutes. Not just once! I'll update the question with that info (I just realized now that I forgot to mention that). EDIT: The question does actually state that, but I'll make it more clear.

Comment: Hmm.i think there’s is a misunderstanding somewhere. I am aware the lambda runs EVERY 5 mins, it was in the diagram. But every time the lambda is invoked by cloudwatch and runs,it will stay alive to process 300 chunks which is 5 mins and then stop.

Comment: Yes, so it runs for 5 minutes and then stops. And then it immediately runs again because the Cloudwatch event fires again. So essentially it is the same as having a server running 24/7, except it costs a lot more money,

Comment: Yes. Just keep in mind LambdaA is cheap (as cheap as the smallest EC2 instance) LambdaB is expensive.